# Mod rewrite - redirecting url with parameter to new url

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I need some help redirecting a url with particular parameter value to a new url. For example how can i redirect these two urls with id 123 and 345 to a new url?

Redirect

http://testserver.xyz.com/abc/content/content.jsp?contentId=123
http://testserver.xyz.com/abc/content/content.jsp?contentId=345

to

https://newpage.silkroad.com/

Any help will be greatly appreciated

TIA

Comment: Please help. I am under time crunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite, add these rules in either your htaccess file in your document root, or your vhost/server config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} contentId=123 [OR]
# add however any more id's here, with `[OR]` flags
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} contentId=345 
RewriteRule ^/?abc/content/content\.jsp$ https://newpage.silkroad.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin. It worked perfectly fine except that it redirects and adds contentId to the url it is redirecting to.                 for example: it redirects to https://newpage.silkroad.com/?contentId=abc                                                       How can i prevent that? Thanks a lot.