# Is there a good way to translate GetParams to PathParams

Tags: apache, ibmhttpserver

We have a JSP application that uses a url like this...

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/project/page.jsp?a=param1&b=param2
```

This is a vendor product and since I am not allowed to just add JAX-RS throw a PathParam and be done with it, I have to figure and Apache rule (I am using IHS technically) or something to translate it into...

```
https://othersubdomain.domain.com/param1/param2
```

What is the best way to handle this without editing the webapp?

Sorry in advance if this is a repeat somewhere.

Comment: This may be one way... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559790/mod-rewrite-redirecting-url-with-parameter-to-new-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SSL vhost that handles the request, you can try something like this -- but it is quite specific to the source and target URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=([^&]+)&b=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/project/page.jsp$ /%1/%2 [PT,E=CHANGEHOST:1]
RequestHeader set Host othersubdomain.domain.com env=CHANGEHOST
```

If you can just redirect, you would skip the last line and just build a URL in the RewriteRule and drop the current flags for [L]

Comment: Awesome I will try this out and give you the check once I confirm.